# Full Text Search on MySQL : Can not search by word after hyphen/dash

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search, amazon-aurora

I have the following record in DB: 'Vinyl Exam - CA Only'

So, when I performed the following search:

```
SELECT  Description
            FROM    products AS p
            WHERE   MATCH (Description) AGAINST ('+Vinyl* +Only*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Record is returned, but in this case:

```
SELECT  Description
            FROM    products AS p
            WHERE   MATCH (Description) AGAINST ('+Vinyl* +Only* +CA*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Item is not returned.

What I should do to return the item in the last case.

Comment: Does any row have all three patterns `+Vinyl* +Only* +CA*`?

Comment: yes, we  have the following record in DB: 'Vinyl Exam - CA Only'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your search isn't working is because by default, there's a minimum length limit for words that can be searched using full text. As far as I remember, it's 3 characters min for `InnoDB` and 4 characters min for `MyISAM`.

Since your word `CA` is only 2 characters long, it will be ignored in search.
You can increase/decrease this character limit by changing the mysql settings.

Basically you need to add following config in your mysql `my.cnf` file (depending upon your database table engine):

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
ft_min_word_len=2
```

Find more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length).